# Asserting TypeScript conditional return type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that converts `Array<[TKey, TValue[]]` to a Map. It's a member of a class where T is the element type, and I'm consuming an array of T. I want to protect against its misuse by inferring that the elements are of the correct type:

```
export class Cool<T> {
  arr: T[];
  constructor(arr: T[]) {
    this.arr =arr;
  }
  toMap<TKey, U>(): T extends [TKey, U[]] ? Map<TKey, U[]> : never {
    const map = new Map<TKey, U[]>();

    this.arr.forEach((item: any) => {
      map.set(item[0], item[1]);
    });
    return map as any;
  }
}
```

This works, but has two "any" casts. By "works" I mean TS correctly prevents you from consuming the API when T does not have the correct type.

I need "any" because

1. TS doesn't think "this.arr" is is `Array<[TKey, U[]]>` and
2. TS doesn't believe the method should return `Map<TKey, U[]>`

I could also cast `this.arr` to `Array<[TKey, U[]]>` which at least makes the callback of `forEach` property typed, but it's even more noise. But I'd much rather be able to type it so that the types inside the function would be inferred to be the non-never version of the return type. (I kind of get why this doesn't work, since I'm only guarding the return type, I just don't know how to set the types up to correctly infer the input types).

Any ideas how I can type this better?